# Android first startup takes too long

Tags: android, performance

I'm creating an app, I'm using some libraries and I noticed that app starts very slow on first startup. So I want to check why. I created new empty app in Android Studio - only one activity with textView 'Hello World'. I think this app should start immediately, but it starts about 3-4 seconds on my Nexus 5X with Android 6 on first startup. Next I can kill app and on next startup app starts immediately. Can someone explain me why or what I should change? It's really simple application, in iOS app starts incomparably faster.

App started is for me situation when I can see textView on screen.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="adamnowicki.myapplication.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

If I override application class

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private final static String TAG = "MyApplication";

    public MyApplication() {
        Log.d(TAG, "constr");
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

}
```

and add this line to manifest:

```
android:name=".MyApplication"
```

I must wait 3-4 seconds for first log

```
D/MyApplication: constr
```

Comment: "it starts about 3-4 seconds" -- what exactly are you doing to start the app? Are you clicking a "run" button in an IDE? Are you tapping a home screen launcher icon? Are you doing something else?

Comment: Without seeing code it is nearly impossible to provide any feedback.

Comment: Please, read [this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community. Add as much detail as possible. The device ID, the Build and version number, the manufacturer, and many many many other informations are relevant here.... Also, read about the Android Activity Lifecycle to understand what "first run" and "open activity" means. If possible also log the ammount of RAM available to the device, and the main programs running (such as anti viruses/etc)

Comment: [Check](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidInternals/article.html#internals) the android startup process

Comment: Are you using instant run?

Comment: `Debug.startMethodTracing()`

Comment: 3-4 seconds after white screen appear on my device. I added code to my question.

Comment: Yes, I'm using instant run. I see now, that if I build this simple app by gradle and use adb install app starts immediately!

Answer (score 0):

If you are launching the app from Android Studio or Eclipse there is a slight delay from APK installed -> app opens -> app starts working.

This only appears to be the problem when using instant run, so I guess there are some features of it that opens it instantly and it takes a while untill the app "knows" *App is open, initialize*